# Reworking Dates and using exceptions

Tags: java, android, date

1)When taking a date String from SQLIte, it looks like this

> 2017-08-20 13:34:08

after parsing this, I want it to look like this

> 20-08-2017 13:34

but with date1.toString() ,what I get is this

> Sun Aug 20 13:34:08 GMT+03:00 2017

How can I control how Date appears?

2) Is it possible to use the simple date format parser outside a try/catch block? It is supposed to go inside a for loop and it is going to waste a lot of time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)
You can control format of the date with using SimpleDateFormat class:

```
String pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
String dateString = format.format(new Date()));
```

2)
You can add throws ParseException to your method header but eventually you need to catch the error somewhere in your code.

Comment: thanks, the forst works perfectly. about the second, if I write 

try{

for (){

parsesomething}

}catch(){}



will it check it every time I parse or when it reaches the end of for?

Comment: If you write your try cause outside of your for loop it will cancel whole loop as soon as a single error is found

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse your Time Pattern to get a date. After you have a date you can format it back to your wanted format.

Your timestamp means: 2017-08-20 13:34:08  -> yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = format.parse("2017-08-20 13:34:08");
```

You may want to format it to another format, then you can get it by using

```
SimpleDateformat newFormat = new SimpleDateformat("hh:mm:ss");
String datestring = newFormat.format(date);
```

You can find a list of all available patterns at 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Take care that you need to catch ParseException, which means that your String is not parseable using your date format.

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

Avoid the troublesome legacy date-time classes, now supplanted by java.time classes. For Android see the ThreeTenABP project.

Parse string after converting to standard ISO 8601 format.

```
String input = "2017-08-20 13:34:08".replace( " " , "T" ) ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input ) ;
```

If you need only minutes and want to drop the finer data, truncate.

```
LocalDateTime ldt2 = ldt.truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.MINUTES ) ;
```

To generate a String in a particular format, search Stack Overflow for `DateTimeFormatter` as this has been addressed many many times.

Please search Stack Overflow before posting. Your Question is basically a duplicate of many others.